# How do you test the type-safetiness of your genericized API?

Tags: java, api, generics, testing, type-safety

You can use e.g. JUnit to test the functionality of your library, but how do you test its type-safetiness with regards to generics and wildcards?

Only testing against codes that compile is a "happy path" testing; shouldn't you also test your API against non-type-safe usage and confirm that those codes do NOT compile?

```
   // how do you write and verify these kinds of "tests"?

    List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();

    objects.addAll(numbers); // expect: this compiles

    numbers.addAll(objects); // expect: this does not compile
```

So how do you verify that your genericized API raises the proper errors at compile time? Do you just build a suite a non-compiling code to test your library against, and consider a compilation error as a test success and vice versa? (Of course you have to confirm that the errors are generics-related).

Are there frameworks that facilitate such testing?

Comment: Needing to visually verify that the compilation of expectedly non-compilable code doesn't work doesn't seem to be in the spirit of unit testing, which should be able to run with the click of a button or a quick keyboard shortcut.  You could maybe write a testcase that verifies that the class files have not been generated automatically (if you've just compiled everything), but it seems you'd get frequent warnings that there are compilation errors in your project that would grow annoyong.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you are worried about:

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Number> numberList = new ArrayList<Number>();
        stringList.add("a string");
        List list = stringList;
        numberList.addAll(list);
        System.out.println("Number list is "+numberList);
    }

which both compiles and runs. PS - wish I could format that nicely

Comment: I think what you need is not Testing but PMD.

Comment: I guess I'm curious why you need to test this. All tests have some sort of precondition, implicit or explicit. In general, unit tests have the precondition that they pass compilation without errors -- and, more often, without warnings.
Unit tests (or even required code) that fail compilation fail the test preconditions and indicate the code isn't ready for test; failed compilations also indicate their own set of errors and indicators as to what was wrong, and so act as a pre-stage test on their own.

Comment: @Mark: I want to test this because I want to use generics in my API, and I want to make sure that it's done correctly, i.e. that it's both flexible (not too restrictive) and type-safe (not too relaxed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this is not testing in the traditional sense (that is - you can't "run" the test), and I don't think such a tool exists, here's what I can suggest:

1. Make a regular unit-test
2. Generate code in it - both the right code and the wrong code
3. Use the [Java compiler API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) to try to compile it and inspect the result

You can make an easy-to-use wrapper for that functionality and contribute it for anyone with your requirements.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are trying to test the Java compiler to make sure it would raise the right compilation errors if you assign the wrong types (as opposed to testing your own api).

If that is the case, why aren't you also concerned about the compiler not failing when you assign Integers to String fields, and when you call methods on objects that have not been initialized, and the million other things compilers are supposed to check when they compile code?!

Comment: How's this answer related to the question?

Comment: You are still missing the point... the OP is not trying to test the compiler, but the design of his types.

Comment: @Bruno his point is valid. Generics are a compile-time only part of Java. The question can be reworded as "How can I test that the compiler will enforce the types I want?"

Comment: @Bringer128: no, the underlying issue is not whether or not the compiler will enforce it, but whether or not the API is flexible enough with regards to generics while still being type safe.

Comment: @poly The key point of my (poorly worded) statement is that you will have to use the compiler to test your code. @Bozho has pointed out how to use a unit test to "test that the compiler will enforce the types you want". The same type of test could be done for other compile-time Java constructs but I agree that generics are complicated enough to warrant this kind of up-front effort.

Answer (score 2):

I guess your question isn't limited to generics. We can raise the same question to non-generic codes. If the tool you described exists, I'll be terrified. There are lots of people very happy to test their getters and setters(and try to enforce that on others). Now they are happier to write new tests to make sure that accesses to their private fields don't compile! Oh the humanity!

But then I guess generics are way more complicated so your question isn't moot. To most programmers, they'll be happy if they can get their damn generics code finally compile. If a piece of generics code doesn't compile, which is the norm during dev, they aren't really sure who to blame.

Answer (score 1):

"How do you test the type-safetiness of your genericized API?" IMHO, the short answer to your question should be:

- Don't use any `@SuppressWarnings`
- Make sure you compile without warnings (or errors)

The longer answer is that **"type safety" is not a property of an API, it is a property of the programming language and its type system**. Java 5 generics is type safe in the sense that it gives you the guarantee that you will not have a type error (`ClassCastException`) at runtime unless it originates from a user-level cast operation (and if you program with generics, you rarely need such casts anymore). The only backdoor is the use of raw types for interoperability with pre-Java 5 code, but for these cases the compiler will issue warnings such as the infamous "unchecked cast" warning to indicate that type-safety may be compromised. However, short of such warnings, Java will guarantee your type safety.

So unless you are a compiler writer (or you do not trust the compiler), it seems strange to want to test "type safety". In the code example that you give, if you are the implementor of `ArrayList<T>`, you should only care to give `addAll` *the most flexible type signature that allows you to write a functionally correct implementation*. For example, you could type the argument as `Collection<T>`, but also as `Collection<? extends T>`, where the latter is preferred because it is more flexible. While you can over-constrain your types, the programming language and the compiler will make sure that you cannot write something that is not type-safe: for example, you simply cannot write a correct implementation for `addAll` where the argument has type `Collection<?>` or `Collection<? super T>`.

The only exception I can think of, is where you are writing a facade for some unsafe part of the system, and want to use generics to enforce some kind of guarantees on the use of this part through the facade. For example, although Java's reflection is not controlled *as such* by the type system, Java uses generics in things such as `Class<T>`, to allow that some reflective operations, such as `clazz.newInstance()`, to integrate with the type system.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Collections.checkedList() in your unit test. The following example will compile but will throw a ClassCassException. Example below is copied from @Simon G.

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Number> numberList = Collections.checkedList(new ArrayList<Number>(), Number.class);
stringList.add("a string");
List list = stringList;
numberList.addAll(list);
System.out.println("Number list is " + numberList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing for compilation failures sounds like barking up the wrong tree, then using a screwdriver to strip the bark off again. Use the right tool for the right job.

I would think you want one or more of:

- code reviews (maybe supported by a code review tool like JRT).
- static analysis tools  (FindBugs/CheckStyle)
- switch language to C++, with an implementation that supports [concepts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C++%29) (may require also switching universe to one in which such an implementation exists).

If you really needed to to this as a 'test', you could use reflection to enforce any desired rule, say 'any function starting with *add* must have an argument that is a generic'. That's not very different from a [custom Checkstyle rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html), just clumsier and less reusable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in C++ they tried to do this with concepts but that got booted from the standard.

Using Eclipse I get pretty fast turn around time when something in Java doesn't compile, and the error messages are pretty straight forward. For example if you expect a type to have a certain method call and it doesn't then your compiler tells you what you need to know. Same with type mismatches.

Good luck building compile time concepts into java :P